# Pattern matching for validating the input

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have to validate the input as

- Asterisks are permitted in positions 2-5.
- Position One should be alphabetic (except for the ~)
  -No characters should accept numbers.
- Other than the exceptions mentioned above, no special characters are allowed

I am trying to build as this.

```
final Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z~][a-zA-Z*]*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(this.mainStaOrgBO.getStaOrgCode());
        final boolean specialCharCheck = matcher.find();
        if (specialCharCheck) {
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Write an example string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^[a-zA-Z~][a-zA-Z*]{1,4}[a-zA-Z]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : start of string
    [a-zA-Z~]       : First char can be letter or ~
    [a-zA-Z*]{1,4}  : char 2 to 5 can be letter or *
    [a-zA-Z]*       : rest of string only letter
$                   : end of string.
```

Comment: Ok so  Asterisks are permitted in positions 2-5. you mean from 2 to 5 not 2 and 5!

Comment: @Panciz: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that Sri with the phrase "Asterisks are permitted in positions 2-5" wanted to say "Asterisks are permitted FROM position 2 TO position 5" not "In position 2 and 5"

Comment: @Panciz: Yes, that's true, that's how my regex works.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the solutions.just want to know what I have to do if 2-5 position is not mandatory.As if I enter input as ~ only, then  it is failing as it is expecting 2nd input also.

Comment: @Sri: Just replace the quantifier `{1,4}` with `{0.4}`

Comment: When we use ~at 1st ploace then it should be ~!@ at 2nd and 3rd place.And when 1st position is Alphabet then 2nd can be either alpha or *.Please help

Comment: @Sri: It's difficult to talk in the comment area. You'd better to ask another question where you'll give some input strings and say which must match and which mustn't.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
[a-zA-Z~]\*[a-zA-Z~]{2}\*[a-zA-Z~]*
```

If the * are optional

```
[a-zA-Z~][a-zA-Z~\*][a-zA-Z~]{2}[a-zA-Z~\*][a-zA-Z~]*
```

Test is here [Online Java Regex Test](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: I correct It * were in position 2-6 insetesad of 2-5 and the ~ is alway allowed

Comment: Can you explain me why you down vote my answer, does the corretted solution work?

Comment: Hi, it is not working.In call cases it is returning false.matcher.matches().I AM USING final Pattern pattern =
                    Pattern.compile(
                            "[a-zA-Z~][a-zA-Z~\\*][a-zA-Z~]{2}[a-zA-Z~\\*][a-zA-Z~]*",
                            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Comment: Post an example string then please.